# Build a tree incorrectly sets the last item added as the root

Tags: c

**changed mutator functions ( kd_tree_add_record, etc..) input to a "pointer to root pointer" root** in order to pass root by reference &root to functions,  and have root updated globally. This was based on user comments. All other bugs mentioned by users was also updated.**

I'm loosely following [this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-dimensional-tree/), plus more optimizations based on [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326970528_PANENE_A_Progressive_Algorithm_for_Indexing_and_Querying_Approximate_k-Nearest_Neighbors).

I'm trying to build a kd-tree, but it seems that root is been changed to the last inserted element, which should not happen, because then the search/traverse wont start in the correct location.

**Actual node structure:**

```
/*kd_tree_node is single leaf of kd tree*/

typedef struct kd_tree_node
{
    struct kd_tree_node* left; 
    struct kd_tree_node* right; 
    float* dataset;  
    float distance_to_neighbor;
    int visited;
    int heap_index;
} kd_tree_node;


/*tree*/
typedef struct
{
   /*in order to  keep track of the kd-tree root*/
   kd_tree_node* _root; 
   /*pointer to internal variables struct*/
   struct kdtree_internals* _internals;  

} kdtree_t;
```

**Updated functions below to pass pointer to root by pointer, based on user comments. The code is also updated based on bugs the user found. Issue persists with segfault.**

Here is the code that adds new nodes internally (ignore inputs const int copying, const float rebuild_threshold, included code that wasn't related to the kd-tree core functionality only):

```
     kd_tree_node*
kd_tree_add_record (kd_tree_node** root, const float data [], int depth,
                    const int k_dimensions,
                    const int copying, const float rebuild_threshold)
{

    /* Tree is empty? */
    if (NULL == *root || NULL == (*root)->dataset || (*root)->dataset[0] ==  FLT_TRUE_MIN) {
        *root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);

    }
    else {

        /* Calculate current dimension (cd) of comparison */
        size_t cd = depth % k_dimensions;
        /*determine current dimension/*/
        /*by using modula operator we can cycle through all dimensions */

        /* and decide the left or right subtree*/
        median = kd_tree_get_column_median(cd);

        if (data[cd] < median) {

           (*root)->left = kd_tree_add_record( &(*root)->left, data, depth + 1,
                    k_dimensions,
                    copying, rebuild_threshold);
        } else {


           (*root)->right= kd_tree_add_record( &(*root)->right, data, depth + 1,
                    k_dimensions,
                    copying, rebuild_threshold);
        }
    }//end else

    return *root;

}
```

**The above function is not exposed to the user, due to too many inputs, the smaller public API is:**

```
void kd_tree_add_points(kd_tree_node** root, const float data []) {

    if (NULL != kd_tree_get_kd_tree()) {
        if (kd_tree_get_kd_tree()->_internals->kd_tree_allow_update) {

           *root =  kd_tree_add_record(&(*root),
                    data,
                    0,
                    kd_tree_get_k_dimensions(),
                    0,
                    kd_tree_get_rebuild_threshold());
            //update the root globally 
                kd_tree_set_root(&(*root));


        } else {
            printf("kd_tree_add_points(),"
                    " kd_tree is locked for rebuild!");
        }
    } else {
        printf("kd_tree_add_points(),"
                " kd_tree is NULL call init");
    }
}
```

**Here is the function that creates a new node (ignore the copying param, I tested with simpler codebase).**

```
kd_tree_node *
kd_tree_new_node(const float data[], const int k_dimensions, const int copying) {

    kd_tree_node * tree = NULL;
    int i = 0;


        tree = get_pre_allocated_kd_tree_node_heap();

        kd_tree_increment_current_number_of_kd_tree_nodes();

/*copy data*/
    for (; i < k_dimensions; i++) {
        tree->dataset[i] = data[i];
    }

    return tree;
}
```

**Here are search functions:**

```
int kd_tree_search(kd_tree_node* root, const float data[])
{
  return kd_tree_search_helper (root, data, 0,kd_tree_get_k_dimensions() );
}

int
kd_tree_search_helper (kd_tree_node* root, const float data[], int depth, const int k_dimensions)
{   
    float median = 0.0; 
    /*Base case*/
    if (NULL == root)
    {
        /*false*/
        return 0;
    }
    else if (kd_tree_points_equal (root->dataset, data,k_dimensions))
    {
        /*true*/
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /*Current dimension*/
        int cd = depth % k_dimensions;
        /* Compare point's current dimension with global median
        and decide the left or right subtree*/
        median = kd_tree_get_column_median (cd); 
        if (data[cd] <  median )
        {
            return kd_tree_search_helper (root->left, data, depth + 1, k_dimensions);
        }
        else
        {
            return kd_tree_search_helper (root->right, data, depth + 1, k_dimensions);
        }

    }
}
```

**This function checks node equality in the search function:**

```
   int kd_tree_points_equal(const float point1[],const  float point2[], 
        int k_dimensions)
{
    int flag = 1;
    if (NULL == point1 || NULL == point2)
    {
        flag = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        float size = k_dimensions;
        /*compare each index*/
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (point1[i] != point2[i])
            {
                /*false*/
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

**Roots getter & setter:**

```
   void kd_tree_set_root(kd_tree_node** root)
{
 /*DONT check/block this function using  kd_tree_allow_update flag, because
    this function is used by kd_tree_rebuild(0 that will also block the rebuild!*/
    if (NULL != kd_tree_get_kd_tree()) {
        kd_tree_get_kd_tree()->_root = *root;
    } else {
        printf("kd_tree_set_root(), kd_tree is NULL,call init. ");
    }
}

kd_tree_node* kd_tree_get_root()
{

  if (NULL != kd_tree_get_kd_tree()) {
        return kd_tree_get_kd_tree()->_root;
    } else {
        printf("Error,kd_tree is NULL, call init");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

(Old output before code changes, to pass pointer to root by reference) After running these functions in my main (included relevant snippets):

```
printf ("Adding kd_tree nodes & Search:\n");

        /*set rebuild thresh hold, when the kd_tree becomes 
         * X times sits previous size*/
        kd_tree_set_rebuild_threshold (2);

        float point [] = {-100, -100, -100};

        /*just for debugging */
        printf ("dimension size=%d\n", kd_tree_get_k_dimensions ());


        kd_tree_add_points (kd_tree_get_root(), point);
        if (kd_tree_search (kd_tree_get_root(), point))
        {

            printf ("%f,%f,%f Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%f,%f,%f Not Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }


        printf ("\n");


        point[0] = -5;
        point[1] = -5;
        point[2] = -5;


        kd_tree_add_points (kd_tree_get_root(), point);
        if (kd_tree_search (kd_tree_get_root(), point))
        {

            printf ("%f,%f,%f Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%f,%f,%f Not Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }



        printf ("\n");


        point[0] = -2;
        point[1] = -2;
        point[2] = -2;


         kd_tree_add_points (kd_tree_get_root(), point);
        if (kd_tree_search (kd_tree_get_root(), point))
        {

            printf ("%f,%f,%f Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%f,%f,%f Not Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }

        printf ("\n");
        point[0] = -1;
        point[1] = -1;
        point[2] = -1;


        kd_tree_add_points (kd_tree_get_root(), point);
        if (kd_tree_search (kd_tree_get_root(), point))
        {

            printf ("%f,%f,%f Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%f,%f,%f Not Found! ", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
        printf ("\n");


        point[0] = -100;
        point[1] = -100;
        point[2] = -100;
```

I get this output (suddenly -100,-100,-100 cant be found!)

```
-alloc ok 
Adding kd_tree nodes & Search:
dimension size=3
-100.000000,-100.000000,-100.000000 Found! 

-5.000000,-5.000000,-5.000000 Found! 

-2.000000,-2.000000,-2.000000 Found! 

-1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000 Found! 

0.000000,0.000000,0.000000 Found! 

1.000000,1.000000,1.000000 Found! 

2.000000,2.000000,2.000000 Found! 

3.000000,3.000000,3.000000 Found! 

4.000000,4.000000,4.000000 Found! 

5.000000,5.000000,5.000000 Found! 

6.000000,6.000000,6.000000 Found! 

-100.000000,-100.000000,-100.000000 Not Found!
```

After looking at the debugger, it seems the root which is passed incorrectly updated to the last insert item, that is the reason "-100.000000,-100.000000,-100.000000 Found!" then its NOT found "

So I ran another test in the main, this time a batch test of inserting 20,000 sequential points & attempting to search for them again:

```
    int i = 0;
    float point[3];
    printf("inserting:\n");
    for (; i < 20000; i++) {
        point[0] = i;
        point[1] = i;
        point[2] = i;
        kd_tree_add_points(kd_tree_get_root(), point);

    }//end insert 
    printf("insertion done!:\n");

    printf("searching:\n");
    int found = 0;
    int notFound = 0;
    i=0;
    for (; i < 20000; i++) {
        point[0] = i;
        point[1] = i;
        point[2] = i;

        if (kd_tree_search(kd_tree_get_root(), point)) {
            found++;
        } else {
            notFound++;

        }

    }//end search 
    printf("search complete!:\n");
    printf("Found:%d\n", found);
    printf("Not Found:%d\n", notFound);
```

The output, was horrible (All except 1 node was been missed!):

```
inserting:
insertion done!:
searching:
search complete!:
Found:1
Not Found:19999
```

The root is being updated to the last insert node, so the search function just doesn't traverse correctly.

Then I noticed a bug in my function `kd_tree_add_record`, after reviewing [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-dimensional-tree/).

After each recursive call the `root->left` or `root->right` pointer must be set, so I updated the `kd_tree_add_record`, see below:

**Updated the function below, to pass root pointer by pointer.**

```
kd_tree_node*
    kd_tree_add_record (kd_tree_node** root, const float data [], int depth,
                        const int k_dimensions,
                        const int copying, const float rebuild_threshold)
    {

        /* Tree is empty? */
        if (NULL == *root || NULL == (*root)->dataset || (*root)->dataset[0] ==  FLT_TRUE_MIN) {
            *root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);

        }
        else {

            /* Calculate current dimension (cd) of comparison */
            size_t cd = depth % k_dimensions;
            /*determine current dimension/*/
            /*by using modula operator we can cycle through all dimensions */

            /* and decide the left or right subtree*/
            median = kd_tree_get_column_median(cd);

            if (data[cd] < median) {

               (*root)->left = kd_tree_add_record( &(*root)->left, data, depth + 1,
                        k_dimensions,
                        copying, rebuild_threshold);
            } else {


               (*root)->right= kd_tree_add_record( &(*root)->right, data, depth + 1,
                        k_dimensions,
                        copying, rebuild_threshold);
            }
        }//end else

        return *root;
    }
```

After that change, I'm getting a segfault in `kd_tree_add_record`, it seems the code is turned into an infinite loop & `(*root)->right` or `(*root)->left` is not updating. Actually looking at the debugger shows regardless of so many recursive calls `root->right` address is "0x7fffff750010".

How can I fix this function to stop crashing & at the same time NOT updated the root (rather updated the root's children root->left or root->right) so the kd-tree, can be traversed correctly?

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Is really an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?
It doesn't feel like it.  I note that it is incomplete in that the structure type is not shown.  It seems to have a `left` and `right` pointer, and a `dataset` pointer or array — but which, and if an array, how big?  It really doesn't help us to see two buggy versions of the same function.  Choose which you think is best.  I don't see a tree printing function.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, those are 2 only functions that are involved plus few lines in main that run the functions. Its add node & search node. That is MINIMAL. I showed 2 versions to demonstrate behavior since I wanted to give insight. And now you ask for more code? However , at the same time you say I have posted too much!!! The node structure i self-explanatory, its a tree with a left & right pointer plus an array of floats. Thanks anyways!

Comment: cyber101, did you intend that comment for @JonathanLeffler?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, apologies yes.

Comment: The amount of code you've posted here is arguably too much, but at the same time it is without question not complete.  I attempted to fill in the blanks you left to create a runnable program, and the resulting program ran cleanly and gave the expected output.  So the problem is in the code you haven't shown us.  This is why we ask for a [mcve].  Anybody should be able to take your code **exactly** as posted, compile and run it, and get the same results.

Comment: Going back to the "minimal" part, this means taking your code and stripping it down to a minimal amount that exhibits the problem, leaving out parts that do not contribute to the error.  So yes, what you've currently posted is at the same time too much and too little.

Comment: Also, try running your code under valgrind.  That should give you a good idea of what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: @dbush , 99% confident the problem is in kd_tree_add_record() , which already posted. I will attempt to update the code soon.

Comment: There is simultaneously too much code and not enough code. We don't know what your structure is — we should not need to look at the references to see that information (your question should be self-contained). There's a `kd_tree_new_node()` function that's missing.  It shouldn't be necessary to search the tree to demonstrate that it is wrong. Printing the tree after you add each node would show whether the insert code is working correctly  — hence my comment about "I don't see a tree printing function". Printing the structure that's causing trouble is a basic technique for debugging them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I added the missing functions that your request.

Comment: @dbush, added the missing functions that were requested.

Comment: @cyber101 I needed to make changes to `kd_tree_add_points` to not return a value and to call `kd_tree_set_root`, and there's still several functions I had to make guesses at what you did.  Still can't reproduce.  My money is on how you're handling memory allocation.  Try running your code through valgrind.

Comment: `if (NULL == root || NULL == root->dataset || root->dataset[0] == FLT_MIN) {
        root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);` seems amiss.  Doing `root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);` make sense in the first case `NULL == root` but the with the other tool, code lose allocations associated with the prior `root`. Sure about `NULL == root->dataset || root->dataset[0] == FLT_MIN`?  Maybe those needs to be  assertions instead?

Comment: @cyber101 Still can't reproduce with your copy of `kd_tree_points_equal`.  We need a [mcve] to help you, preferably as a single code block rather than several we need to stitch together.

Comment: @cyber101 Last chance before the bounty runs out: Post a *single* block of code that others can cut-and-paste without modification, compile, run, and get the same results you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kd_tree_new_node` is not initializing all the pointers (especially `left` and `right`), so you get garbage in there and that causes a segfault. Basically, your ISNULL part of the if clause is not hit for the new nodes.

You have to review you methods carefully. You seem to think you work with references to pointers, or pointers to pointers, but are actually working with pointer values. If you assign something to the pointer, it is not being updated in the pointer variable that was passed inside.

Comment: `kd_tree_new_node` calls `get_pre_allocated_kd_tree_node_heap` which appears to do the actual allocation.  However that function hasn't been shown, so we have no way of knowing if what you say is true.

Comment: @dbush Ok granted, I am working under the assumption it basically just returns some allocated memory.

Comment: @kutschkem, I made that update thanks for noticing.

Comment: @kutschkem, i updated functions to accept "pointer to pointer" so I can pass my root by reference (&root). I also allocated memory for left & right pointers based on your comments. Please see the posted code. It compiles but I'm getting the same issue, which is the "root is not being updated" in `kd_tree_add_record()` and therefore its a infinite and finally segfault. Really appreciate if you can look at this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, post lacks info needed to solve, yet some insights will help OP.

---

**Missing declarations**

Added the following to get code to compile.  I'd rather see OP's version.

```
typedef struct foo kd_tree_node;

struct foo {
  kd_tree_node *left;
  kd_tree_node *right;
  float *dataset;
  struct {
    int kd_tree_allow_update;
  } *_internals;
};

float median;

float /*    */kd_tree_get_column_median(unsigned);
int /*      */kd_tree_get_k_dimensions();
float /*    */kd_tree_get_rebuild_threshold();
int /*      */kd_tree_points_equal();
kd_tree_node* kd_tree_get_kd_tree();
kd_tree_node* kd_tree_new_node();
void /*     */kd_tree_set_rebuild_threshold(int);

// OP's coded functions
kd_tree_node* kd_tree_add_record(kd_tree_node *root, const float data[],
    int depth, const int k_dimensions, const int copying,
    const float rebuild_threshold);
kd_tree_node* kd_tree_add_points(kd_tree_node *root, const float data[]);
int kd_tree_search(kd_tree_node *root, const float data[]);
int kd_tree_search_helper(kd_tree_node *root, const float data[], int depth,
    const int k_dimensions);
```

**Too causal use of mixed `int/unsigned`**

As implicit converting `int` to `unsigned` is a source of failures, code should be more careful to insure the range did not cause wrap-around.

```
int depth, const int k_dimensions,
...
assert(depth >= 0); // add
assert(k_dimensions > 0); // add
unsigned cd = depth % k_dimensions;
```

Code has two functions with `cd` yet with different types.  Candidate problem.

```
unsigned cd = depth % k_dimensions;
int      cd = depth % k_dimensions;
assert(cd >= 0); // add
```

As `cd` is used for indexing, the go-to type is `size_t`, an *unsigned*.

**Unclear use of `FLT_MIN`**

Why compare for equality with a *not the smallest* `float`?

```
root->dataset[0] == FLT_MIN
```

Perhaps code should be

```
root->dataset[0] == FLT_TRUE_MIN  // Smallest non-zero FLT
// or
root->dataset[0] <= FLT_MIN  // Avoid wee numbers and negatives
// or 
fabsf(root->dataset[0]) <= FLT_MIN  // Avoid all wee numbers
```

**NOT found**

Posting `kd_tree_points_equal()` source would help.

**Debug tip: seg-fault**

Add code before each array access to test range of index.

**Debug tip: Printing FP**

For debugging, use `"%e"` or `"%g"` instead of `"%f"`.  Easier to notice small non-zero numbers and less verbose for huge numbers,

Comment: I added `kd_tree_points_equal()`  under heading 'test node equality". I replaced int cd to size_t cd & FLT_MIN to FLT_TRUE_MIN in my IDE but not in the code on the stack. The segfault is an infinite loop  in the function `kd_tree_add_record`

Comment: In the version of `kd_tree_add_record` were Im getting segfault the root is being set `root->left = kd_tree_add_record (root->left, data, depth + 1,
                                       k_dimensions,
                                       copying, rebuild_threshold);` the other version were there is NO segfalu however the root is being set incorrectly to the last element the root is being set like this `root- = kd_tree_add_record (root->left, data, depth + 1,
                                       k_dimensions,
                                       copying, rebuild_threshold);`

Comment: @cyber101 [I added kd_tree_points_equal() under heading 'test node equality"] is unclear.  The definition of `kd_tree_points_equal()` is not in the post.  Nor is "test node equality"

Comment: apologies dont know what happened , please check again `kd_tree_points_equal()` is included now.

Comment: @cyber101 In `kd_tree_points_equal()`, when one pointer is `NULL` and the other is not, code reports _equal_.  This may be the issue.  IAC, recommend to return not equal in those cases.